# Angular ng-model issue on time input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm having an issue using ng-model with time input on my app. I've searched around and couldn't find any other questions regarding this but I may be mistaken.

I have time inputs with ng-model and am getting this weird "1970-01-01T09:00:00.000Z" value.

[Here's a fiddle recreating my issue](http://jsfiddle.net/t3m6r/63/)

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="time" step="900" ng-model="startTime" />
    <input type="time" step="900" ng-model="endTime" />
    <pre>
        Start Time: {{ startTime }}
        End Time: {{ endTime }}
    </pre>
</div>
```

Only dependency I'm using is angualr v1.3.15

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're getting a javascript date, with the time portion set to whatever you selected in the input.  It's showing in Zulu time (UTC), so for me if I pick 2:30 AM, it displays 1970-01-01T08:30:00.000Z.  Ignore the date portion, the time portion is what I selected.

If you want to see the selected time adjusted to your local time zone, use the date filter.

```
Start Time: {{ startTime | date:"hh:mm a" }}
End Time: {{ endTime | date:"hh:mm a" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) and display the time as you wish, there are many many options.
This is one example:

```
Start Time: {{ startTime | date : 'hh:mm' }}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/t3m6r/65/)